# How to use string value outside the class in Android?

Tags: android, spinner

I am working with AlertDialog box where user gives instruction about the product through alertDialog box. In dialog box there are 2 spinner, buttons etc. When I select spinners options it should take selected value and toast it, but it's taking default value.

I need to save this value on server, so it should be accurate; it's saving default value to the server. I don't know where its wrong?

Here is my SubMenu Activity:

```
      public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status="";
    static String FLAG = "image";
    Integer i = 1;
    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud..com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud.granddubai.com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                //                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("main_menu_items");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    // map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {


            final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();





            customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));









            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup
                    , null);
            customDialog.setView(dialogView);

            final  Spinner crust, adds;
            // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button



            ImageLoader imageLoader= new ImageLoader(dialogView.getContext());
            final ImageView desimage = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);

            // final  CircleImageView desimage =(CircleImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(arraylist.get(position).get("image"), desimage);

            final TextView heading = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h1);

            final EditText spins = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinst);


            final String specialInstr=spins.getText().toString();

            heading.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("name"));

            final String hed=heading.getText().toString();

            final Button dcr=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);

            final Button incre=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
            final  String crusttext, addstext;

           /* crust = (Spinner)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(SubMenu.this, R.array.Crust_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            crust.setAdapter(adapter);
            crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            crusttext = crust.getSelectedItem().toString();

            adds = (Spinner)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);

            ArrayAdapter adapteradds = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(SubMenu.this, R.array.AddsOn_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapteradds.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adds.setAdapter(adapteradds);
            adds.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            addstext = adds.getSelectedItem().toString();*/

            final Button cncl = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc);
            cncl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
            final ImageButton crssbtn = (ImageButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
            crssbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });




            Button _decrease = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
            Button _increase = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);

            final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);
            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.adson);

            ArrayList<String> alspinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> alspinner2 = new ArrayList<>();


            final String[] _spvalue1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crust_array);
            final String[] _spvalue2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AddsOn_array);
           for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue1.length; i++) {
                alspinner1.add(_spvalue1[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue2.length; i++) {
                alspinner2.add(_spvalue2[i]);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner2);

            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);









            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        final    String spinner1Selection = alspinner1.get(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
            Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, spinner1Selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





            final TextView _value = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.value);
            i = Integer.parseInt(_value.getText().toString());

            final String _stringVal;
            _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String _stringVal;
                    Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                    if (i > 0) {
                        i = i - 1;
                        _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                        _value.setText(_stringVal);

                        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, ""+_stringVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("src", "Value can't be less than 0");
                    }

                }
            });

            _increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String _stringVal;

                    Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                    i = i + 1;
                    _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                    _value.setText(_stringVal);
                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, ""+_stringVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });




            Button altok=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alrtok);

            altok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //is chkIos checked?

                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();












                    final String spli=spins.getText().toString();
                    final   RadioGroup rgroup = (RadioGroup) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgrp1);




                    final String rval1;
                    final  RadioButton rbtn;

                    final int selectedId = rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();



                    rbtn = (RadioButton) dialogView.findViewById(selectedId);
                    rval1 = rbtn.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, rval1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, spli, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                        // Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(SubMenu.this, AddToCart.class));
//your intent code here
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this,"Please Give Full Information!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            })
                    {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("dish_name", hed);
                            params.put("type",rval1);
                            params.put("addson",spinner1Selection);
                           // params.put("crust",crusttext);
                            params.put("special_instruction",specialInstr);

                            /*params.put("Last_Name",lname);
                            params.put("email", email);
                            params.put("Gender", rval);
                            params.put("password", passwrd);
                            params.put("confirmPasw",cpasswrd);
                            params.put("DOB",dobr);
                            params.put("sms_subscrb",status);
                            params.put("Mobile_No",mobile);*/
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SubMenu.this);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                }
            });















            //  crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            // public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {


           /* final Button ok = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });*/










            customDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {


          //  Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this,"The planet is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use the value of string outside the spinner?

Comment: You need to learn to properly indent and format your code. As it is now, it's unreadable.

Comment: sorry for tht....but can u see spinner

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a bit more readable. When writing posts and comments here, please try to refrain from txtspk such as "plz" and "shud" and "u". If words like "please", "should" and "you" are too much trouble to write, Stack Overflow may not be for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is not well formatted to understand easily so here is the hint:

As you are using these two array list to setting data to adapter to their respective Spinners:

```
ArrayList<String> alspinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> alspinner2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

you have Spinners: spinner1 and spinner2

Now where ever you want selected string from spinner you can get like:

```
String spinner1Selection = alspinner1.get(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
String spinner2Selection = alspinner2.get(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Updated answer:

```
@Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("dish_name", hed);
                            params.put("type",rval1);
                            params.put("addson",
                            alspinner1.get(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                           // params.put("crust",crusttext);
                            params.put("special_instruction",specialInstr);

                            /*params.put("Last_Name",lname);
                            params.put("email", email);
                            params.put("Gender", rval);
                            params.put("password", passwrd);
                            params.put("confirmPasw",cpasswrd);
                            params.put("DOB",dobr);
                            params.put("sms_subscrb",status);
                            params.put("Mobile_No",mobile);*/
                            return params;
                        }
```

Comment: it shud value which will get only after selecting the item ..plz see my updated qus ..i have put ur code  and in params i m sending tht string to database,,..in database its saving default value

Comment: You are doing wrong with my code. check updated answer. Because before selecting any value you stored the spinner1Selection(by default which is first item always)

Comment: can u tell me for button _incre and _drec thr also i cannot access to  _stringVal

Comment: You can directly access that value from _value.getText(). because finally your are updating value to _value TextView on _decrease or _increase click.

Comment: found java.land,charsquen required java.lang.string

Comment: here _stringVal is getting the value if i icre or decr the button ..i can see in toast also but if i m accessing outside onclick it gives me red line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132561/discussion-between-z-al-and-ready-android).

Comment: do u have any idea abt tht